# Performance of Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm quite new to the EF Core. I always used the EF 6.0 and never had to use an include. Now the question comes up how I should work with these includes. I figured out three possible options and wanted to know which would you prefer to use/which is the fastest and why?

In these samples my intention is to get the details of a club. I want to check if a club with the corresponding id exists and then get the whole information.

Option 1:

```
using (var context = new TrainingSchedulerContext())
{
    var clubs = context.Clubs.Where(c => c.Id == clubId);
    if (clubs.Count() == 0)
        return NotFound();

    var club = clubs.Include(c => c.Memberships)
        .Include(c => c.MembershipRequests)
        .Include(c => c.TrainingTimes)
        .Include(c => c.AdminRoles)
        .SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Option 2:

```
using (var context = new TrainingSchedulerContext())
{
    var club = context.Clubs.Include(c => c.Memberships)
            .Include(c => c.MembershipRequests)
            .Include(c => c.TrainingTimes)
            .Include(c => c.AdminRoles)
            .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == clubId);

    if (club == null)
        return NotFound();
}
```

Option 3:

```
using (var context = new TrainingSchedulerContext())
{
    var club = context.Clubs.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == clubId);
    if (club == null)
        return NotFound();

    club = context.Clubs.Include(c => c.Memberships)
        .Include(c => c.MembershipRequests)
        .Include(c => c.TrainingTimes)
        .Include(c => c.AdminRoles)
        .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == clubId);
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: You should use Any() in Option1 and Option3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go from worst to best:

- **Option 3**: this is obviously the worst. You are downloading the entire item into memory *just for throwing it away*. This is a waste of resources.
- **Option 1**: this is not the best way because you are executing 2 queries against the database, one for `Count` and another one for `SingleOrDefault`. The first one is not needed, hence:
- **Option 2**: this is the best case because if the item does not exist, nothing will be downloaded from the database, so you don't have to worry about that, and it's also a single database call.

Comment: I guess the last (best) you meant Option **2**. It's not a single db query in EF Core, but still the best you can get.

Comment: @IvanStoev Oops, typo, still not awake, thanks. I was pretty sure it was only a single SELECT that's executed, will have to check again

Comment: It depends if the navigation properties are references or collections. By the names I assume these are collections, so this will execute 1 + 3 = 4 database queries in case the main entity exists and 1 database query if it doesn't.