# EF core- view queries of lazy loading

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

We are using asp.net core 2.1 and EF core 2.1.

We are currently using lazy loading in EF core and we have noticed that some of our server requests take now way too much time to run.

Is there a way to get from ef core (via code) the queries that it ran for this specific user/request and for each query see how much time it takes.

We want to make an alarm that will send us all this info when we reach a threshold of a too slow request.
Thanks

Comment: this could be a duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49447231/performance-of-entity-framework-core

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performance of Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49447231/performance-of-entity-framework-core)